# cut command behaving differently when its output is “ * ”

Tags: shell, awk, grep, cut

I am trying to create a shell script, below is a part of which where i am trying to extract some value from a record in a file:

```
tgt_val=cat $file_name | grep "$string_name" | cut -d"|" -f$column_no
```

This work perfectly when the specified column has some numeric or string value however it fails when the column has value as `*`, eg:

```
102|Sam|*|USA
```

This command would work correctly for column 1, 2 & 4

However in case of column 3 it gives me output as all the files in present directory.

Someone please help over this.

Comment: `cut -d "|" -f1-4 <<< '102|Sam|*|USA'` works for me. Can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: On what OS?  Works on OS X Mavericks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable)

Comment: The problem is that you need `echo "$tgt_val"` with quotes instead of `echo $tgt_val`.  As an aside, your code is not correcly transcribed; you need `tgt_val=$(...)` to capture the output into the variable (what you have is a syntax error, unless the value of `$file_name` happens to be the name of a valid command).

Comment: Thanks @tripleee that worked. It was a problem with my $tgt_val. It worked when i echo'ed the value as echo "$tgt_val"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my $tgt_val. It worked when i echo'ed the value as echo "$tgt_val"